# Add CXF to Intellij Web Services Facet

Tags: intellij-idea, cxf, intellij-idea-2018

I have created a maven project using archetype [ [org.apache.cxf.archetype » cxf-jaxws-javafirst](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf.archetype/cxf-jaxws-javafirst) ]. I have also added tomcat 8.5.34 as run/debug configurations.

But when I try to add CXF framework support, I cannot because the OK button is *disabled* all the time (even after browsing to the framework folders)

Find image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgJzD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Idea doesn't support Apache CXF version higher than 2.7.16.

Check the ticket [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140221)

and If you are interested vote to get it fixed.